# Is there an existing LCID --> 'Country Flag' function in the dot net framework?

Tags: .net, localization

Does anyone know of a way to get an icon or image of some sort from the dot net framework based on an LCID, Culture or Region?

Obviously, I could write a case statement for this and provide my own images, but if someone else has done the hard yards (and is maintaining appropriate images) then I'd rather use existing code.

I've looked at the CultureInfo and RegionInfo classes which hold information like currency symbols, Display Names, abbreviations etc. but I can't find any 'flags'.

Is this too much of a political hot potato?

Answer (score 0):

Create a resource file and localize it. That way you can use different icon/images for each language

[.NET - Localization using Resource file](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Localization.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is what I'm trying to avoid doing. I'd prefer to not to do a build every time a country I've never heard of changes their flag. I'm trying to discover if the dot net framework (or even the windows os) already has a function that returns an icon for an LCID.

Comment: It also has the limitation of getting the resource for your specific localized app - if your app needs to lets say list the countries with the icons next to them, you need a lookup table mapping LCID/culture to icon.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that's closer to what I'm trying to do. I know I'm not alone in wanting to be able to display a list of countries with flags beside them. It isn't that this is HARD to do, it's the re-inventing the wheel that I'm not so keen on.

Answer (score 0):

Framework won't have image/icon libraries.

Here's the list of Cultures and LCIDs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx

That will help you find some flags icons on the internet and then map them using that table.

I would suggest you just rename all the icons to the LCID or culture name and then lookup function just loads [lcid].ico or [lcid].png from disk or resource embedded in the file.