# Is there a way to get a flag image from a C# CultureInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, localization, cultureinfo

If I have a `CultureInfo` instance, is there any simple way — built-in, through a framework or via the OS — to obtain a matching "flag" icon matching that culture? This would avoid having to create a separate lookup.

I couldn't find a member function to do the job in [the documentation for `CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but perhaps there is some other not-too-taxing approach that involves other .NET classes that I haven't found.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7748425/560648

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: Ah yes, probably. Neither of its answers are upvoted or accepted though so I can't mark this one as a dupe. Perhaps we can accrue some good answers here.

Comment: The correct, literal answer is "no, neither .NET nor Windows provides the feature you want". Maybe you should reword your question so that a correct answer actually addresses your real need, rather than restricting it to "I don't want to do any extra work". For better or worse, if you want this, it will involve some real work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: My "real need" is to find out the answer to precisely what I stated as the question. If the answer is no then the answer is no. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit still your question may be useful to other people looking for a way to actually display such an image, so I replied with a way to do that without using a separate data lookup but with a file lookup in a collection of images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no simple, built-in way, through the .NET framework or the Windows operating system, to obtain a matching "flag" icon for a given `CultureInfo` instance.

Answer (score 5):

Extending Alex's answer. Once you have the ISO code, you can use this simple library to produce an `ImageSource` of the flag (from the famfamfam set) from the two character string:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/famfamfam-flags-wpf

It's not built in, but it is easy to use.

Images end up looking like this:

[image]

Comment: Im looking the same would been nice if u provided example code for the drop down

Comment: Sample code for use in a drop down is available in the linked repo.

Answer (score 4):

As @Peter Duniho said, there is no built-in way in the .NET Framework. Furthermore, CultureInfo represent locales, while flags represent countries, and there are many situations where the two do not perfectly match. You may incur in diplomatic problems if you come across some users.

Anyway, if you want something simple, you may want to use [famfamfam's flag icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/), which have been conveniently named after the ISO 3166-alpha1 2 letter country code, and then convert your CultureInfo to a RegionInfo given the locale, and finally get the two letter ISO region name:

```
var r = new RegionInfo(yourCultureInfo.LCID);
var flagName = r.TwoLetterISORegionName + ".gif";
```

finally, if such a file exists, then display it. Please note that you may use the PNG versions, and that different languages may map to the same country (I'm thinking of Switzerland, where they speak 4 official languages).

Comment: This is great as an auxiliary answer, and fair point re locale vs country. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Guess what! It’s now possible to do this in C# and is supported by most platforms including Windows 11 devices! You can just use the emojis and you don’t need a flag icon pack!

On Windows 10 it only works on Firefox browsers for now. But it does work with iOS, MacOS & Android apps

```
public string GetFlag(string country)
{
  var regions = CultureInfo.GetCultures (CultureTypes. SpecificCultures).Select(x => new RegionInfo(x.LCID));
  var englishRegion = regions.FirstOrDefault(region => region.EnglishName.Contains(country));
  if (englishRegion == null) return "";
  var countryAbbrev = englishRegion.TwoLetterISORegionName;
  return IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(countryAbbrev);
}
public string IsoCountryCodeToFlagEmoji(string countryCode) => string.Concat(countryCode.ToUpper().Select(x => char.ConvertFromUtf32(x + 0x1F1A5)));
```

https://itnext.io/convert-country-name-to-flag-emoji-in-c-the-net-ecosystem-115f714d3ef9

Comment: Seems to work, but sadly it only shows the letters in my Blazor application running in the Edge browser. The reason can be found in this comment section: https://dev.to/jorik/country-code-to-flag-emoji-a21/comments

Comment: Because windows does not ship with emojis?

Comment: Yes, in the forums they say they don´t ship with emojis for political reasons.