# Dropdown List Country With CountryFlags

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Does asp.net have any classes who represent countryFlag as like CultureInfo who represent country list? I want to show countries with flags in asp.net using C# without using database. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Why not creating your own custom class?

Comment: share your method to show flag .İf you ask us yes .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a flag image from a C# CultureInfo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27733705/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-flag-image-from-a-c-sharp-cultureinfo)

Comment: Thank You For your suggestion..But I am new in C#..so I don't know how to create own custom class...So Please can you tell how I will create own custom class..-@@Rohit Rohela

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it on client side, I would recommend you to use [semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com).
Use dropdown element with [flags](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/flag.html). [Here is example](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best way try image sprite. Refer https://www.flag-sprites.com/ . Simple example given below.

```
    <select>
        <option value="1">Albania<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-in" alt="India" /></option>
        <option value="2">Albania<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-usa" alt="United States" /></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion..I have dowload flags.css,flags.min.css and flags.gif from  https://www.flag-sprites.com/ ...but when I have used your example as like...
 <select>
        <option value="1">Albania<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-in" alt="India" /></option>
        <option value="2">Albania<img src="blank.gif" class="flag flag-usa" alt="United States" /></option>
    </select>
------It Is Showing img cannot be nested within option...
Can You tell me How Solve this problem....
Thanks

Comment: sorry i missed out .. For showing image u need to include css for flag flag-usa(all countries)